# What is the right way to bind data with RadListView using Angular + Nativescript template?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

**Overview**

I want to create below datatable in nativescript

[image]

after some searching on internet I found that this could be done using `RadListView`. So I find the from [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=aW6fJ2) and [ListView/getting-started](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/getting-started)

**Problem**

The problem which I'm facing right now is my `RadListView` didn't bind with data.

developer tools snap:

[image]

console snap:

[image]

output:

[image]

**What I've tried**

**home.component.html**

Tried this code:

```
<page xmlns:lv="nativescript-ui-listview">
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton ios:visibility="collapsed" icon="res://menu" (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"></NavigationButton>
    <ActionItem icon="res://navigation/menu" android:visibility="collapsed" (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"
        ios.position="left">
    </ActionItem>
    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Home"></Label>
</ActionBar>
<lv:RadListView [items]="inbox">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate  let-item="item" let-i="index"> 
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <Label fontSize="20" [text]="item._Transactions" />

            <Label fontSize="14" [text]="item._PendingYourAction" />

            <Label fontSize="14" [text]="item._PendingNextLevelAction" />

            <Label fontSize="14" [text]="item._CompletedTransactions" />
        </StackLayout>
</ng-template>
</lv:RadListView>
```

Tried this code:

```
<lv:RadListView [items]="inbox">
    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <Label fontSize="20" [text]="inbox._Transactions" />

            <Label fontSize="14" [text]="inbox._PendingYourAction" />

            <Label fontSize="14" [text]="inbox._PendingNextLevelAction" />

            <Label fontSize="14" [text]="inbox._CompletedTransactions" />
        </StackLayout>
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array/observable-array";

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    inbox: ObservableArray<Inbox>;
    constructor() {
        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
        sideDrawer.gesturesEnabled = true;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.inbox = new ObservableArray<Inbox>();
        this.inbox.push(new Inbox("Purchase Request",0,0,"View"));
        this.inbox.push(new Inbox("Purchase Order",0,0,"View"));
        this.inbox.push(new Inbox("Receipt",0,0,"View"));
        this.inbox.push(new Inbox("Payment Advice",0,0,"View"));
        console.log(this.inbox);
    }

    onDrawerButtonTap(): void {
        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
        sideDrawer.showDrawer();
    }
}

export class Inbox {
    public _Transactions: string;
    public _PendingYourAction: number;
    public _PendingNextLevelAction: number;
    public _CompletedTransactions: string;

    constructor(Transactions: string, PendingYourAction: number, PendingNextLevelAction: number, CompletedTransactions: string) {
        this._Transactions = Transactions;
        this._PendingYourAction = PendingYourAction;
        this._PendingNextLevelAction = PendingNextLevelAction;
        this._CompletedTransactions = CompletedTransactions;
    }
}
```

**Question**

Kindly help me on this what I'm doing wrong in my code. What is the right way to bind data with RadListView using Angular. I'm using angular 6 with nativescript.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the same issue for someone else this morning by suggesting the following

Which platform(ios/android) are you testing this? It is very important for ios to provide height and width to the listview or it's parent component. There are couple of other thing you could to try for further debugging

1. Push data to inbox in (loaded) method of RadListView.
2. Try to assign listview in loaded like this

   onListLoaded(args) {this.listView = args.object;}

and refresh the listview by `this.listview.refresh();` once you pushed all the inbox data.

3. Have an activityIndicator first and hide the list. Hide the indicator once you have reports and make lost visible.
4. Push data to temp array and once all items are pushed, assign that temp array to reports.

   _tempInbox.push(new Inbox("Purchase Request",0,0,"View"));
   this._inbox = _tempInbox;

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between the syntax used for Angualr with Core. We don't use `<Page>` element or `xmlns` in Angular, those are designated for Core development.

For **Angular**, you will have to import the `NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule` from `nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular`. Then simply use `<RadListView ...>` tag.

You may simply create a new Playground and drag the `RadListView` component from list, it will create a nice and simple working example.